How to test DLQ on Spring Cloud Stream?
I'm struggling to guarantee that DLQ is working properly on test code. Here is my properties file.
spring.application.name=parsing-processor
spring.cloud.function.definition=parsing

spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.parsing-in-0=input
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.parsing-out-0=output

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=inflow
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=1

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enable-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-name=inflow-parsingdlq

And this is my test code.
@SpringBootTest (
    properties = [
        "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.cache.max.bytes.buffering=0",
    ]
)
class DlqTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val inputDestination: InputDestination,
    private val outputDestination: OutputDestination,
    private val converter: CompositeMessageConverter,
) {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val rawString = readFileAsString("failing_rawstring.json")

        val inflowMessage = InflowMessage(rawString)
        // When
        val headers = MessageHeaders(mapOf("contentType" to "application/json"))
        val message = converter.toMessage(inflowMessage, headers)
        inputDestination.send(message, "input")

        val payload = outputDestination.receive(2000, "inflow-parsingdlq")

        // Then
        assertThat(payload).isNotNull()
    }
}

The payload is always null. How can I fix it? I used EmbeddedKafka before, but it failed too. Is there a example for it?

The outputDestination does not correspond to dlq. It only corresponds to the actual bindings. In your case inflow-parsingdlq is a topic in Kafka that has no binding. your application. So you can use spring-kafka directly to interact with such destination.

@OlegZhurakousky Can I create a binding that bounds to dlq and use it for testing?

@OlegZhurakousky Solved it! The key is to prevent application from replacing actual binders to testing binders.
Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/testing.html#embedded-broker-with-springjunitconfig-annotations:~:text=the%20project%20configuration.-,If,-your%20application%20uses
